# Avoid malloc() when doing unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

Try to use has map in C++. The problem is that when I add a constant entry like `mymap["U.S."] = "Washington";`,  it used `malloc()` (I verified when using gdb with breakpoint on `malloc()`).  Unnecessary calls to malloc will reduce the performance, hence I am trying to avoid it as much as possible.  Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> mymap;
  mymap["U.S."] = "Washington";
  std::cout << mymap["U.S."] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I know the malloc is necessary when the scope of a key is short, since one  may need to use mymap[key] even after the key is destroyed. But in my case, all the keys (a huge number of them) will be persisitent in memory .

Comment: You might want to look up "heterogeneous lookup". It is a C++14 feature. Additionally, you can use certain arena allocators that reduce the calls to `malloc`, for example [Howard Hinnant's `short_alloc`](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html).

Comment: Well, the map has to store the data somewhere. It's a hashtable, after all. And since the size is a runtime quantity, it *must* use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Write your own [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) based on a huge static array.

Comment: @dyp, thanks for the tips, seems "heterogeneous lookup" is about binary search, slower than hash table lookup.   Also, not sure how to use `short_alloc()` here.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that heterogeneous lookup in the current StdLib is only supported for *ordered* associative containers (like `std::map`). The short allocator can simply be used as a replacement for the current default allocator; this will however not prevent allocation for converting the `char const*` arguments of `mymap[..]` to `std::string`s. Those allocations however are subject to the Small String Optimization. If you're using libstdc++, you could try using `vstring`.

Comment: @Angew,  yes, there is a need to have a node to store key and value.  The point here is, if the key is relatively stable (doesn't disappear),  it would be nice to have just a pointer to the key (as a block of bytes) and length of the key,  instead of copying the all the bytes from the key in an allocated space.

Comment: @codingFun You can very easily code such a class yourself and use it as a key, or use just about anything with a custom hasher and comparator.

Comment: @Angew, that's true.  Just wonder if there is an existing one that I can use.

Comment: @gha.st, thanks for mentioning allocator, I will take a look at it too.